# I have inserted a row, I want to get it's ID and plus it with an int and insert in that row

Tags: c#, sql

I have inserted a row into my table, and I want to get it's ID and plus it with an int and inserted in that row.

But I don't know how to get it's ID.

Here is the insert code:

```
objCommand.Connection = objConnection;
objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Moin " +
                         " (Title, TotalID, Code ) " +
                         "VALUES (@Title , @TotalID, @Code )";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
objCommand.Connection = objConnection;
            objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Moin " +
                " (Title, TotalID, Code ) " +
                "VALUES (@Title , @TotalID, @Code ) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
object id = objCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`OUTPUT` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) of SQL Server in your query - it can return any of the just inserted value (here I'm assuming your column is called `ID` - adapt as needed):

```
objCommand.Connection = objConnection;
objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Moin(Title, TotalID, Code ) " +
                         "OUTPUT Inserted.ID " +
                         "VALUES (@Title , @TotalID, @Code ); "
```

and then execute it like this:

```
int result = (int)objCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Since you're returning just one row and one column (just the INT), you can use `.ExecuteScalar()` to retrieve that value back from the `INSERT` statement.

With the `OUTPUT` clause, you can return any values just inserted - not just the identity column. So you could also return values that are filled by the database with default values, or whatever you need. If you return multiple values, you need to use a data reader to read them all - `ExecuteScalar()` only works for a single value.

But, as Anders correctly mentioned - using an ORM like Entity Framework would do all of this automatically for you and you wouldn't have to deal with those raw SQL commands anymore....

Answer (score 0):

Building SQL commands in strings should be considered a legacy technique. If you use Entity Framework or linq-to-sql the retrieval of the id is handled automatically for you.

With pure SQL, use the `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function to retrieve the id of the inserted element.